# Complex parsing query

Tags: python, parsing

I have a very complex parsing problem. Any thoughts would be appreciated here. I have a test.dat file.The file to be parsed looks like this:

```
*   Number                  =              40

Time =  0
  1   10.13   10   10.11   12   13
  .
  .

Time =  n
  1   10   10   10   12.50   13
  .
  .
```

There are N time blocks and each block has 40 lines like shown above. What I would like to do is add e.g. the 1st line of first block , then 1st line in  block #2 .. and so on to to a new file -test_1.dat. Similarly, 2nd line of every block to test_2.datand so on.The lines in the block should be written *as is* to the new _n.dat file.  Is there any way to do this? The number I have assumed here is 40, so if the * number = 40 there will be 40 lines under each time block.

regards,
Ris

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  If it's not, please add a little info about what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually I have generated a file test.dat ( output) and  I am in process of extracting the slices of time blocks, for help in visibility of my output. I could parse most of the other things in test,dat. Just that this particular problem is bugging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file in as a list of strings (call it fileList), where each string is a different line:

```
f = open('filename')
fileList = f.readlines()
```

Then, remove the "header" part of your file with

```
fileList.pop(0)
fileList.pop(0)
```

Then, do

```
outFileContents = {} # This will be a dict, where number -> content of test_number.dat
for outFileName in range(1,41): #outFileName will be the number going after the _ in your filename
    outFileContents[outFileName] = []
    for n in range(40): # Counting through the time blocks
        currentRowIndex = (42 * n) + outFileName # 42 to account for the Time = and blank row
        outFileContents[outFileName].append(fileList[currentRowIndex])
```

Finally you can loop through outFileContents and write the contents of each value to separate files.

Comment: If you want to make it more flexible, you can read from the first line to get the number there (call it `num`). Then change `range(1,41)` to `range(1,num+1)`, change `range(40)` to `range(num)`, and change `42` to `(2+num)`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, this looks good. Just one short question, Could you please explain the outFileContents = {}. Should I locate a block that starts with Time locate this line and index the other lines from here?

Comment: `outFileContents = {}` just initializes the `outFileContents` variable to be an empty dictionary. By popping two entries from the list you've basically made Time = 0 your 0th line. So everything else can reference from there.